# Getting NaN when summing values in for loop

Tags: node.js, api, nan

I want to sum the values from an API response. The values are stored in JSON format. My code looks like this:

```
var returnCode;
var getUrl = "url";
returnCode = httpGet(getUrl);
var objekt = JSON.parse(returnCode);

function httpGet(url){
  var response = requestSync(
    'GET',
    url
    );
    return response.body;
}

var price = 0;

for(i=0; i<30; i++)
{
    price = price + objekt.data.sales[i].price;
}
price /= 30;
console.log(price);  //displays NaN
console.log(objekt.data.sales[1].price);  //displays correct price of one element
```

The problem is that when I try to output price it returns NaN, but if i just display a value of a single element it works fine. Any ideas why it does that? there are 30 elements in the array BTW.

Comment: check the typeof value make sure how it comes in and parse it to number if it's not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually Json values are coming as string

Change the for loop

```
for(i=0; i<30; i++)
{
    price = price + parseInt(objekt.data.sales[i].price);
}
```